# How to programmatically select item in primeng p-menu?

Tags: angular, primeng

Any idea how to programmatically select an item in a primeng p-menu? Code is straightforward:

```
  <p-menu #menu [popup]="true" [model]="configMenuItems" appendTo="body" [style]="{'text-align': 'left'}"></p-menu>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" pTooltip="Select Site" tooltipPosition="left" onclick="this.blur();" (click)="menu.toggle($event)">
    {{selectedSite.DisplayName}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging by the lack of answers and the lack of documentation, I switched to using a p-dropdown instead.

Answer (score 0):

This has the workaround-kinda-vibe, but it works! Note that this would trigger the actual click on the item.

```
@ViewChild('menu', { static: false }) menu: Menu;
configMenuItems: MenuItem[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    configMenuItems: MenuItem[] = [
        {
            id: 'menu.fooConfig',
            icon: PrimeIcons.HOME,
            routerLink: '/home',
        },
        {
            id: 'menu.blaConfig',
            icon: PrimeIcons.COG,
            routerLink: '/home',
        }
    ];
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // Assuming that you retreive the initial menu item id from somewhere...
  const menuItem = this.whateverService.getSelectedMenuItem();
  this.menu.itemClick(new MouseEvent('click'), this.configMenuItems.find(item => item.id === menuItem.id));
}
```